# How I can move focus from tabitem title to content in WPF?

Tags: wpf, focus

How I can move focus from tabitem title to content of this tabitem by pressing downarrow?
I tried to use KeyboardNavigation but Keyboardfocus still doesn't move when I press down or up key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, ok.  I didn't know about it. I have looked through my questions and pointed out some answers.

Answer (score 1):

I created an attached property to address a similar problem. When you press a certain key on a ContentControl (TabItem), it focuses on the content. The XAML looks like this

```
<TabControl Focusable="False">
        <TabItem Header="Main" local:Focus.ContentOn="Down">
            <Stackpanel>
               <TextBox />
            </Stackpanel>
        </TabItem>
```

And the Attached Property:

```
public static class Focus
{
    public static Key GetContentOn(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Key)obj.GetValue(ContentOnProperty);
    }

    public static void SetContentOn(DependencyObject obj, Key value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ContentOnProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ContentOn.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentOnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ContentOn", typeof(Key), typeof(Navigate),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Key.None, OnContentOnChanged));

    private static void OnContentOnChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = o as ContentControl;
        if (control != null)
            control.KeyDown += FocusContent;
    }

    private static void FocusContent(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.FocusedElement == sender)
        {
            var control = sender as ContentControl;
            if (control != null && control.HasContent && GetContentOn(control) == e.Key)
            {
                ((FrameworkElement)control.Content).MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.First));
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```